# ImportError: cannot import name 'CypherError' from 'neo4j.v1' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neo4j/v1/__init__.py)

Tags: python, postgresql, neo4j, fastapi, neomodel

I am trying to connect a graph base to a project tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql.
But every time I come across an import error.
Please tell me, maybe someone faced a similar problem.
Backend launch log:

```
Checking for script in /app/prestart.sh
Running script /app/prestart.sh
INFO:__main__:Initializing service
INFO:__main__:Starting call to '__main__.init', this is the 1st time calling it.
INFO:__main__:Service finished initializing
INFO [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/app/initial_data.py", line 1, in <module>
from app.dbase.init_db import init_db
File "/app/app/dbase/init_db.py", line 14, in <module>
from neomodel import db as neodb
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neomodel/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .core import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neomodel/core.py", line 9, in <module>
from neomodel.util import Database, classproperty, _UnsavedNode, _get_node_properties
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neomodel/util.py", line 8, in <module>
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth, CypherError, SessionError
ImportError: cannot import name 'CypherError' from 'neo4j.v1' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neo4j/v1/__init__.py)
```

The code I was callin:

```
import logging
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from app import crud, schemas
from app.core.config import settings
from app.dbase import base

from neomodel import db as neodb
from neomodel import config, install_all_labels

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def init_db(dbase: Session) -> None:
    user = crud.user.get_by_email(dbase, email=settings.FIRST_SUPERUSER)
    if not user:
        user_in = schemas.UserCreate(
            email=settings.FIRST_SUPERUSER,
            password=settings.FIRST_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD,
            is_superuser=True,
        )
        user = crud.user.create(dbase, obj_in=user_in)

        neodb.set_connection("bolt://neo4j:password@neo4j:7687")
        person = Profile(email=settings.FIRST_SUPERUSER)
        person.save()
        country = Country(name="Russia")
        country.save()
        person.country.connect(country)
```

Comment: It looks like you're using incompatible versions of neo4j and neomodel?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am currently using
`neomodel = "^3.3.2"`
`neo4j = "^4.1"`
`neo4j-driver = "^4.1.1"`.  Didn't think they might be incompatible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements for neomodel state that it requires neo4j 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, or 3.3

See the documentation: https://neomodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#requirements

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, looking for more solutions, I chose a fork of neomodel with support for the latest version of neo4j, such as https://github.com/JVemmer/neomodel.git